# Find msqid using known key_t in linux c

Tags: c, linux, ipc, message-queue

I have two independent processes, both create a message queue using `msgget()` with the same key (key_t = 9189, supplied as cmd line arg for both process) and they send and receive messages successfully.
   Now I have a third independent monitoring process (supplied with the same key_t = 9189) which has nothing to do with the messages but it wants to monitor the status of the message queue, so I am thinking to use `msgctl()` but it needs `int msqid` as an argument.

---So how to find the `msqid` using known `key_t`?.
---If I have to use `msgget()` to find the `msqid`, since this monitoring process has to monitor status of several such message queues isn't it using `msgget()` will create overhead just to obtain `msqid`?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the `msqid` only by `msgget`, plain and simply.